# Use MsiEnumRelatedProductsA from Win32 API in RUST

Tags: winapi, rust, windows-installer

What modules should I import from winapi crate so that I can use MsiEnumRelatedProductsA from Win32 API?

I tried to connect dependencies like this:

```ini
[dependencies]
winapi={ version = "0.3.9", features = ["msi"] }
```

But I am getting an error
`winapi`, with features: `msi` but `winapi` does not have these features.

Comment: `MsiEnumRelatedProductsA` [doesn't appear](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aretep998%2Fwinapi-rs%20MsiEnumRelatedProductsA&type=code) to be part of the `winapi` crate. You'll either have to provide your own declaration, or use the [`windows`](https://crates.io/crates/windows) or [`windows-sys`](https://crates.io/crates/windows-sys) crate instead (which do [expose this API](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/?search=MsiEnumRelatedProductsA)).

Comment: @IInspectable, thank you! I will try with [windows](https://crates.io/crates/windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`winapi`](https://crates.io/crates/winapi) crate is well past its time. It hasn't seen an update in 3 years, and should be considered abandoned. If it doesn't provide a Rust mapping for an API, there's no hope to ever get it in at this point.

[`MsiEnumRelatedProductsA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msi/nf-msi-msienumrelatedproductsa) is one such API that never made it in, so you'll have to look into alternatives:

1. Continue using the `winapi` crate, and supply declarations of the missing imports in your own code (the import library generated from [msi.def](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs/blob/0.3/i686/def/msi.def) names the respective symbols, so this should also successfully link).
2. Switch to a crate that's actively maintained. Both the [`windows`](https://crates.io/crates/windows) and [`windows-sys`](https://crates.io/crates/windows-sys) crates are, and either one provides a declaration ([`MsiEnumRelatedProductsA`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/ApplicationInstallationAndServicing/fn.MsiEnumRelatedProductsA.html), and [`MsiEnumRelatedProductsA`](https://docs.rs/windows-sys/0.48.0/windows_sys/Win32/System/ApplicationInstallationAndServicing/fn.MsiEnumRelatedProductsA.html)).

The second option is preferred. `windows-sys` is closer to `winapi` in describing the raw binary interface. `windows` implements a number of transformations on top of the API that make it easier and safer to use. [Choosing between the windows and windows-sys crates](https://kennykerr.ca/rust-getting-started/windows-or-windows-sys.html) outlines the differences and helps you decide.